# Wordpress CSS / Less not working

Tags: css, wordpress, less

I'm trying to add CSS to my Theme. I write in less and use grunt to compile it into a style.css file. Grunt works fine and the css file looks correct. In my online account I can see the css file and wordpress identifies the style.css as the stylesheet, but the css isnt working on the website. Can you spot my fault?

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>

</title>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

functions.php

```
<?php function adding_css() {
wp_enqueue_style('css-style', get_stylesheet_uri()); } add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adding_css' );
```

style.css

```
#footer{display:flex;flex-flow:wrap}.footer .try{color:red;height:2px}body{height:20px}html{width:5px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh damn I found my fault.

I included the functions.php in a js subfolder, where Wordpress didnt find it. Now it works.